# Deciphering cause of death and surname of informant

Tags: england, palaeography, death-records, cause-of-death

[image]

Can someone help me with deciphering the informant's surname (first line in the second box)and cause of death (first line in the first box)?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to G&FH! Which line in which box are you having trouble with? Or is it everything that's visible?

Comment: Hi, I'm struggling with Lucy's surname in the second box and the word before certified by in the first box.

Answer (score 8):

The cause of death is '*senectus*', or put more simply, just '[old age](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/senectus)'.

The grand-daughter's surname appears to be '*Brumley*' (most of the letter-forms appear to match other examples in that sample)